# Attempt to invoke interface method com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

App is getting force stop on viewing details

I have tried different methods to connect to my firebase user ids but its giving null pointer exception and showing attempt to invoke interface method 
Firebase Auth state listener is throwing error

View details.class

```
public class ViewDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference myref;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private String userId;

    ListView listView;

    private TextView name,email,phone,shopname,shopaddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_details);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.inventorybackground);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
        shopname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shopname);
        shopaddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shopaddress);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myref=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userId=user.getUid();

        myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            getdetails get=new getdetails();
            get.setName(ds.child(userId).getValue(getdetails.class).getName());
            get.setEmail(ds.child(userId).getValue(getdetails.class).getEmail());
            get.setPhone(ds.child(userId).getValue(getdetails.class).getPhone());
            get.setShopname(ds.child(userId).getValue(getdetails.class).getShopname());
            get.setShopadd(ds.child(userId).getValue(getdetails.class).getShopadd());

            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
            array.add(get.getName());
            array.add(get.getEmail());
            array.add(get.getPhone());
            array.add(get.getShopname());
            array.add(get.getShopadd());

            ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mAuthListener!=null)
        {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    private void toastMessage(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because `mAuthListener` is never instantiated.

Do this in your `onCreate()`

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // Your logic
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: im logged in already and fetching user details but by going to activity its getting me logged out automatically idk why by using getCurrentUser();

Comment: did this answer solved your question issue about NullPointerException ? if yes, mark this question as correct and open another one with your other issue